# How to get stringContent from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a client Call my API service as this:

```
var paramDiction = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"datefROM", "2018/1/1"}};
string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramDiction);
var stringContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// call the API service
var x = await _httpClient.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
```

I tried many ways to get the stringContent from Server Side, but still can't get it. I'm I on the wrong way?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetStringContent")]
    public IActionResult GetStringContent()
    {
        var stringContent = Request.HttpContext.ToString();

        return stringContent;
    }
```

Don't know why the Request here is a httpRequest, only have the HTTPContext and this httpContent can't read the content out like

```
    Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: because you are returning `null` from your method, i.e. `GetStringContent()`

Comment: Sorry I was debugging before return to check the value.
Edited to avoid misleading.

Comment: what is in your `url` variable?

Comment: My url is local service like "Http://192.168.0.1/apiPath" and the break point stopped in this method. So Url should be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all for API Methods you normally return a `HttpResponseMessage` that you can create with `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode, Message)`.

Now to your question, in Asp.Net an API Method has parameters according to what you're expecting to be sent. For Example in your case your Method signatrue would look like this `public HttpResponseMessage GetStringContent([FromBody] Dictionary<string, string> stringContent)`. The `[FromBody]` Attribute is used in Post Methods to signal that the Content is coming from the request body

Comment: Thanks! I got the result now!